# Is lcov file which has 2 other lcov files simply concatenated a valid lcov file?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, code-coverage, test-coverage, lcov

I have 2 lcov report files I want to concatenate to send to Sonar instance. One if from unit tests and second one is from e2e tests ( Selenium ).

So I intend to do

```
cat unit.lcov >> e2e.lcov
```

Is this valid or structure of new lcov file will be not valid/correct/parsable and I should use some other dedicated tool? ( I know about https://www.npmjs.com/package/lcov-result-merger )